# How to programmatically declare a route in Quarkus?

Tags: java, quarkus

As seen in the [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive), the standard way of declaring a route in Quarkus is with the `@Path()` annotation, like so :

```java
@Path("myPath")
public class Endpoint {

    @GET
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

This will create the route `GET /MyPath`. However, `@Path` being an annotation, I have to give it constant expression.

I would like to be able to declare a route with a non constant expression, something like `@Path(MyClass.class.getSimpleName())`

I tried to implement something like this:

```java
public class Endpoint {

    public void initialize(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {
        declareRoute(MyClass.class.getSimpleName(), HttpMethod.GET, this::hello);
    }

    public String hello() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }

    public void declareRoute(String path, HttpMethod method, Consumer handler) {
        // TODO implement
    }
}
```

This would create the route `GET /MyClass` But I have no idea how to implement `declareRoute()`. I tried to inject the Vertx `Router` since Quarkus seems to use it, but I did not find a way to add a route. Is this doable, and if so, how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You essentially need to do something like:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class BeanRegisteringRoute {

    void init(@Observes Router router) {
        router.route("/my-path").handler(rc -> rc.response().end("Hello, World!"));
    }
}
```

See [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-routes#using-the-vert-x-web-router) for more information